# How to improve file field browse buttons in firefox- rails 4 with bootstrap

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, firefox

Rails 4 app, Bootstrap 3

I have a form with multiple file upload fields.

The html:

```
<%= f.file_field :image, class: "form-control" %>
```

It looks great in all browsers except firefox; here the bottom of the browse button is cut off and it doesn't look professional:
[image]

What's the best way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Jasny Bootstrap to style the file upload element?  If not, take a look [Jasny Bootstrap](http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/javascript/#fileinput)